# Using the glossaries package in other languages.

Tags: languages, glossaries

I have just started using the glossaries package, and as I'm writing my documents in icelandic  I run into a certain problem. The glossaries package assumes the words are in two forms, singular or plural, but for icelandic the same word can easily take 10 forms.

I guess there are some people here writing in other languages who may have a good solution for this (I tried to search, but this package gets a little too technical for me, beyond the standard options of the package).

What I'm looking for is preferably a way to put in what form should be presented in the main text, maybe `\gls[word presented in text]{glossaryentry}` or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `\glsdisp` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossary
\newglossaryentry{minex}{name={minimal example},description={bla}}

\begin{document}

How to create a \glsdisp{minex}{special minimal example} \dots

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also use `\glslink` insted of `\glsdisp` to make it an hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

While your question is likely long since resolved for your own application, if these forms follow rigid rules of conjugation that are readily identifiable as you type you could also consider using a key to add another form that you could explicitly define.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

    \glsaddkey
    {base}          % new key
    {\relax}        % default value if "base" isn't used in \newglossaryentry
    {\glsentrybase} % analogous to \glsentrytext
    {\Glsentrybase} % analogous to \Glsentrytext
    {\glsbase}      % analogous to \glstext
    {\Glsbase}      % analogous to \Glstext
    {\GLSbase}      % analogous to \GLStext


\makeglossary
\newglossaryentry{minex}{name={minimal example},description={bla},base={contextually minimal example}}

\begin{document}

How to create a \glsbase{minex} \dots

Next genairic use of \gls{minex}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```