# Package and/or macro for producing a bi-lingual dictionary/glossary?

Tags: glossaries, dictionaries

A use case is simple, say you write a computer science text book for pirates. Then, each time you mention a term, you may need to mention its English equivalent. So, instead of writing,

```
 Ye first proggie today will be ``Ahoy, World!''
```

You would like to write:

```
 Ye first \term{proggie} today will be ``\term{Ahoy}, World}!''
```

where, in a separate file, you make a list of all terms, and their English equivalent, e.g. `\termdef{ahoy}{hello}`, and `\termdef{proggie}{program}`.

The `\term` macro (use of the word in context) should do the following:

1. Add a footnote of the English equivalent.
2. Add itself to a Pirates-to-English dictionary
3. Add itself to an English-to-pirate dictionary.

Now, it seems as if the `glossaries` package can almost do that. The main difficulty is in dealing with word forms. `glossaries` can do plurals, but the Pirates language has many more word forms, e.g., you could write in your term definitions file,

```
`\termdef{progie}{program}`
`\termdef{progee}{program}`
```

Or better yet, instead of defining all possible word forms, have the text mention the principal formthe text, refer to the principal form of the word.

```
After writing the \term[progie]{progee}, you have to compile it.
```

What I would like is that the the first footnote includes the principal word form, not the current variant.

Also, I am not sure as to how I should use the package to produce two glossaries instead of one, each with its own sorting.

(A [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6123/using-the-glossaries-package-in-other-languages) dealt with a similar topic (Icelandic vs. Pirates), but the difficulties remain: first footnote should mention the principal form of the word, and the issue of producing two glossaries instead of one.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial answer, redefine `glossaries` internal (?) control sequence `\glsdisplayfirst` to (a) display the current word form, and (b) to place a footnote with the root form. Here is how:

```
\renewcommand\glsdisplayfirst[4]{#1\footnote{\glslabel=#2}}
```

Note that the `\glslabel` control sequence provides the root form of the word. The following definition will make it easy to use any word form in your text:

```
\newcommand\newterm[2]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{name=#1,description=#2}}
\newcommand\term[2][\relax]{\ifx#1\relax\gls{#2}\else\glsdisp{#1}{#2}\fi}
```

Here is a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
    \renewcommand\glsdisplayfirst[4]{#1\footnote{\glslabel=#2}}
    \newcommand\newterm[2]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{name=#1,description=#2}}
\newcommand\term[2][\relax]{%
    \ifx#1\relax
        \gls{#2}%
    \else
        \glsdisp{#1}{#2}%
    \fi
}
    \makeglossaries

\newterm{ahoy}{hello}
\newterm{progee}{program}
\newterm{picaroon}{pirate}



\begin{document}
\section{Programming for \term[picaroon]{Picaroons}}
   Ye first \term[progee]{proggie} today will be ``\term[ahoy]{Ahoy}, World!''.
Nice \term{progee}, ain't it?

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I still do not know how to automatically create the inverse dictionary.