# Best way for creating a lexicon/dictionary

Tags: lists, glossaries

I am trying to create kind of a lexicon in LaTeX for listing popular scientists and their inventions, for example. So, I wanted to ask, which way is the best to achieve something like this in LaTeX. It would be cool, if the output of the dictionary is alphabetically sorted. My first thought was using the glossaries package but I wonder if there is a better way for achieving this.
~JackboyPlay

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149754/is-there-an-environment-document-class-for-dictionaries referring to the `dici` package - that doesn't sort automatically and it seems unmaintained, but maybe it can be useful.

Comment: And another suggestion in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/creating-a-standalone-glossary using the `glossaries` package.

Comment: Maybe a description list, or the `nomencl` package, or just the `\paragraph` or some custom macro, maybe a bib file ..  but the scientists should be referenced-linked elsewhere? Maybe  the list should be re-ordered in some way? or do you want just a list? It's hard to say what you need  without knowing what you want to do.