# Symbols as glossary entry indicators?

Tags: symbols, glossaries

Concerning the book I am about to write, I brood over another subject, which merits in my view a separate thread.

As the book will be a classical paper book and not an e-book, I would like to mark any technical term in the text, which is explained in a glossary, so that the reader is aware whenever further explanation is available at the end of the book. Of course, the labelling shall be done in an unobtrusive way, so that the decent text layout will not be spoilt.

The use of different text styles (like italics, bold, different fonts, etc.) is not an option, as they are already applied for other highlighting purposes. Hence, I thought of some symbols alongside the technical term to be marked, like a `\leftpointright` after the term or a superscripted `\diamond`.

How can I realise that concretely with the package `glossaries`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `\defglsentryfmt` is one way to define a `prefix` to the gls entry as shown in the text.

Since a 'classical' paper book is being designed, `hyperref` is not needed and as such no ugly splitted links occur.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={Foo},
  description={Foo is the Foo, nothing more}
}

\defglsentryfmt{$\rightarrow$\glsname{\glslabel}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\gls{foo}

\blindtext

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In order to test the code, I copied it into a new tex file. However the compilation fails with this error message: _ERROR - Cannot find control file 'Glossary-Symbol-Test.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1_ Is the package `glossaries` perhaps incompatible with the backend `biber`?

Comment: @Oli: I don't have  `biblatex` included, so your error is not related to my solution, since I don't use `biber` here

Comment: Problem half way solved: The error above was due to the settings of "Fast compilation" in Texmaker. When I type F2 (Latex), F6 (PDFLatex) and then F7 (Show PDF), I get the compiled text. However the glossary is missing, thus the `\printglossaries` command is not executed. What is my mistake?

Comment: @Oli: You need to execute the `makeglossaries` script, which is part of the `glossaries` bundle. I.e. if your document is called `foo.tex`, you have to compile it first, then use `makeglossaries foo` and then compile again to get the cross-references correct. I never use such stuff like TeXMaker, I can't say how this is set up in the building tools dialog.

Comment: Great, it works - thanks! The symbol can also be placed after the term as a sufix. For those who are - like me - not so familiar with the compilation in a terminal, cf. [link] (http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3461/wie-kompiliere-ich-in-der-eingabeaufforderung-im-terminal?Seite=1#3499).

Comment: Try adding `\GLS{foo}, \glspl{foo}, \glsdisp{foo}{bar}.` ;-) It's much better to do `\defglsentryfmt{$\rightarrow$\glsgenentryfmt}` instead.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Your comment looks interesting, but to be honest, I didn't got it completely so far. May you outline the mentioned benefits compared to the solution by Mr. Hupfer in some more detail, please? Thanks!

Comment: @Oli The commands `\gls`, `\Gls`, `\GLS`, `\glspl`, `\Glspl`, `\GLSpl` and `\glsdisp` all use the same underlying code to determine what text is displayed when they're used (e.g. `\gls` shows the singular and `\glspl` shows the plural, alternate text may be supplied for first use, the upper case versions capitalise the text). This code is given by `\defglsentryfmt` for a particular glossary type, but the code given here forces it to always display the value of the name key regardless of the calling command (`\gls`, `\GLS` etc), so the variants no longer work as advertised.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: I'm deeply impressed. Thank you very much for your effort and detailed explanations.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of different ways of changing the format used to display terms defined by the `glossaries` package. It depends on exactly which commands you want to affect.

Let's start with a MWE that has three glossary types: `main` (the default), `acronyms` and `symbols`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[symbols,acronyms]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{matrix}{name={matrix},plural={matrices},
 description={rectangular array of quantities}}

\newglossaryentry{M}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{M}}},sort=M,
 description={a \gls{matrix}}}

\newacronym{filo}{FILO}{first in last out}

\begin{document}
A \gls{matrix}, denoted \gls{M}. Lots of \glspl{matrix}.
\Glspl{matrix} are a rectangular array of quantities.
No indexing, linking, formatting: \glsentrytext{matrix}.
The identity \gls{matrix}['s] diagonal consists of ones.

First use: \gls{filo}. Next use: \gls{filo}.
Full form: \acrfull{filo}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

The commands in the form `\glsentry...` (such as `\glsentrytext`) simply expand to the value of the appropriate key, without any formatting or indexing etc.

The [`\gls`-like commands](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:gls-like) `\gls`, `\Gls`, `\GLS`, `\glspl`, `\Glspl`, `\GLSpl` and `\glsdisp` all have their format governed by `\glsentryfmt` by default, but the format for a particular glossary can be overridden using `\defglsentryfmt`, but any change to this format must apply various tests to determine the calling command and whether or not this is the first time the entry has been used. (See section [6.3 Changing the format of the link text](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glsdisplay) of the user manual.) There's a convenient command `\glsgenentryfmt` which can be used for generic terms if only minor modifications are required. There are various different approaches if you want to change the format for abbreviations.

The [`\glstext`-like commands](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glstext-like) such as `\glstext` and `\glsname` don't use this special display format, since the text to display is that supplied by the corresponding key when the entry was defined (possibly with any text inserted via the final optional argument, as in `\glstext{matrix}['s]`). So any change to `\glsentryfmt` or use of `\defglsentryfmt` won't make any difference to the way these commands are displayed.

Both the `\gls`-like and `\glstext`-like commands have their text wrapped with `\glstextformat` which by default just does its argument. The simplest way of showing how a change in this command modifies the document is to add some colour:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[symbols,acronyms]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{matrix}{name={matrix},plural={matrices},
 description={rectangular array of quantities}}

\newglossaryentry{M}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{M}}},sort=M,
 description={a \gls{matrix}}}

\newacronym{filo}{FILO}{first in last out}

\begin{document}
A \gls{matrix}, denoted \gls{M}. Lots of \glspl{matrix}.
\Glspl{matrix} are a rectangular array of quantities.
No indexing, linking, formatting: \glsentrytext{matrix}.
The identity \gls{matrix}['s] diagonal consists of ones.

First use: \gls{filo}. Next use: \gls{filo}.
Full form: \acrfull{filo}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Note that `\glsentrytext{matrix}` hasn't been changed, nor have the names in the glossaries (except for the instance of `\gls{matrix}` which occurs in the description for the `M` entry).

So if you want an indicator for every use of the `\gls`-like or `\glstext`-like commands, you simply need to redefine `\glstextformat` as appropriate.

This get a little more complicated if you only want to change the format for certain types of entries or for certain types of commands. If you only want to change the format for the `\gls`-like commands, you can redefine `\glsentryfmt` or use `\defglsentryfmt` for a specific glossary.

Let's first try redefining `\glsentryfmt` to insert a prefix symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[symbols,acronyms]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\glsentryfmt}{$\rightarrow$\glsgenentryfmt}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{matrix}{name={matrix},plural={matrices},
 description={rectangular array of quantities}}

\newglossaryentry{M}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{M}}},sort=M,
 description={a \gls{matrix}}}

\newacronym{filo}{FILO}{first in last out}

\begin{document}
A \gls{matrix}, denoted \gls{M}. Lots of \glspl{matrix}.
\Glspl{matrix} are a rectangular array of quantities.
No indexing, linking, formatting: \glsentrytext{matrix}.
The identity \gls{matrix}['s] diagonal consists of ones.

First use: \gls{filo}. Next use: \gls{filo}.
Full form: \acrfull{filo}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Note that the prefix doesn't appear for the acronym because the abbreviation mechanism has overridden the format for the `acronym` glossary using `\defglsentryfmt`, so `\glsentryfmt` isn't used for entries in that glossary.

Now let's suppose I remove the `acronym` package option so that the entries defined using `\newacronym` are placed in the `main` glossary instead of having their separate list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\glsentryfmt}{$\rightarrow$\glsgenentryfmt}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{matrix}{name={matrix},plural={matrices},
 description={rectangular array of quantities}}

\newglossaryentry{M}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{M}}},sort=M,
 description={a \gls{matrix}}}

\newacronym{filo}{FILO}{first in last out}

\begin{document}
A \gls{matrix}, denoted \gls{M}. Lots of \glspl{matrix}.
\Glspl{matrix} are a rectangular array of quantities.
No indexing, linking, formatting: \glsentrytext{matrix}.
The identity \gls{matrix}['s] diagonal consists of ones.

First use: \gls{filo}. Next use: \gls{filo}.
Full form: \acrfull{filo}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The document now looks like:

[image: image of document]

Now the only entry with a prefix is the `M` entry in the `symbols` glossary. This is because `\newacronym` has again triggered `\defglsentryfmt` for the glossary associated with its entry, which is now the `main` glossary.

This use of `\defglsentryfmt` by `\newacronym` can be overridden by adding another `\defglsentryfmt` after `\newacronym`, which I've done below. I've also added `\glsname{filo}` (which is a `\glstext`-like command that uses the text supplied by the `name` field).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\glsentryfmt}{$\rightarrow$\glsgenentryfmt}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{matrix}{name={matrix},plural={matrices},
 description={rectangular array of quantities}}

\newglossaryentry{M}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{M}}},sort=M,
 description={a \gls{matrix}}}

\newacronym{filo}{FILO}{first in last out}

\defglsentryfmt{\glsentryfmt}

\begin{document}
A \gls{matrix}, denoted \gls{M}. Lots of \glspl{matrix}.
\Glspl{matrix} are a rectangular array of quantities.
No indexing, linking, formatting: \glsentrytext{matrix}.
The identity \gls{matrix}['s] diagonal consists of ones.

First use: \gls{filo}. Next use: \gls{filo}.
Full form: \acrfull{filo}.
Name: \glsname{filo}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This now produces:

[image: image of document]

This doesn't use the prefix for `\glsname` but rather confusingly has the prefix twice in `\acrfull` in front of the long form and then in front of the short form.

Setting the acronym style using `\setacronymstyle` drops both prefixes from `\acrfull` but the use of `\defglsentryfmt` has broken the acronym style, which relies on the entry format using `\glsgenacfmt` for abbreviations and `\glsgenentryfmt` for non-abbreviations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\glsentryfmt}{$\rightarrow$\glsgenentryfmt}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\newglossaryentry{matrix}{name={matrix},plural={matrices},
 description={rectangular array of quantities}}

\newglossaryentry{M}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{M}}},sort=M,
 description={a \gls{matrix}}}

\newacronym{filo}{FILO}{first in last out}

\defglsentryfmt{\glsentryfmt}

\begin{document}
A \gls{matrix}, denoted \gls{M}. Lots of \glspl{matrix}.
\Glspl{matrix} are a rectangular array of quantities.
No indexing, linking, formatting: \glsentrytext{matrix}.
The identity \gls{matrix}['s] diagonal consists of ones.

First use: \gls{filo}. Next use: \gls{filo}.
Full form: \acrfull{filo}.
Name: \glsname{filo}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Instead, the entry format must check for abbreviations which can be done with `\ifglshasshort`:

```
\renewcommand{\glsentryfmt}{%
 $\rightarrow$\ifglshasshort{\glslabel}{\glsgenacfmt}{\glsgenentryfmt}}
```

This modification produces:

[image: image of document]

This has corrected the first use of the abbreviation, but there's still no prefix in front of `\glsname` since that command isn't governed by `\glsentryfmt` (or `\defglsentryfmt`).

You can introduce some variations. For example, only prefix regular terms (not abbreviations):

```
\renewcommand{\glsentryfmt}{%
 \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}{\glsgenacfmt}{$\rightarrow$\glsgenentryfmt}}
```

Or only prefix on first use:

```
\renewcommand{\glsentryfmt}{%
 \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}
 {\glsgenacfmt}% abbreviation
 {\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{$\rightarrow$}\glsgenentryfmt}% regular term
}
```

There's even more flexibility with the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) package where entries can be assigned categories, and minor adjustments can be made according to the category or the category's attributes. (See [this example from the `glossaries-extra` gallery](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/sample-name-font.shtml).)

When redefining `\glsentryfmt` or using `\defglsentryfmt`, it's important to remember not to break the checks that determine the calling command (`\gls`, `\glspl` etc) which are performed by `\glsgenentryfmt` and `\glsgenacfmt`.

For example, the following modification breaks the document:

```
\renewcommand{\glsentryfmt}{$\rightarrow$\glsentryname{\glslabel}}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

The plural form `\glspl{matrix}` has been rendered as singular. The case change in `\Glspl{matrix}` has been lost (as well as being reduced to the singular form). The inserted material in the optional argument of `\gls{matrix}['s]` has been lost. The abbreviation no longer shows the long form on first use. Using `\glsname` rather than `\glsentryname` makes things even worse as it nests the rather complicated internal command used by both `\gls` and `\glsname`, and anyone adding `hyperref` to the document may encounter problems caused by nested hyperlinks.