# Acronyms expansion with glossaries in fusional language

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, russian

I might be more theoretical question, but anyway. 
I like to use `glossaries` package and the way it handles with acronyms, expanding them in the first use. It perfectly matches for English, where phrases could be the same form in all situations. But what about fusional languages, like Russian. There are a lot of forms of single phrase, which should be used in different cases. 
Maybe be some way to track first use and set it manually?

I found similar question for German: [How to use glossaries for different grammatical acronym forms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178725/how-to-use-glossaries-for-different-grammatical-acronym-forms?rq=1)

But I need about 12 forms for every acronym in Russian, and it seems to be a useless work and overkill in this case.