# Is it possible to show a custom text for the long part of an abbreviation?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

Using the glossaries-extra package, it is possible to define the used terms and their abbreviation for convenient and consistent use within the document.
But handling inflections within a sentence becomes unexpectedly difficult, as I write in German and the plural forms are not sufficient.
A simple solution is to use `\glslink` and `\glsdisp` to show a custom text, but this has several shortcomings shown in the example below.
My understanding of LaTeX hacking is insufficient to grasp the internals of the glossaries packages and I cannot estimate whether creating a custom command to handle this is feasible.

## Example

To compile this, execute `pdflatex test`, `bib2gls --record-count test`, `pdflatex test` in this order.
Also, to show why `\gsldisp` is insufficient, the example only shows the abbreviation at all, when the term is used at least twice.

### File `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=blue!30!white}

\usepackage[record,abbreviations,nomain]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[abbreviation]{long-short-desc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{nohyperfirst}{true}
\renewcommand{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={glossary},selection=all]
\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{abbreviation}{1}
% Show only terms that are used more than once:
\renewcommand{\printunsrtglossaryhandler}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\GlsXtrTotalRecordCount{#1}>1}%
  {\glsxtrunsrtdo{#1}}%
  {}%
}
\begin{document}
% Good; No abbreviation shown:
The first mention with a different inflection ``des \glsdisp{Vektorraum}{Vektorraums}''.

% Bad; Should show choose abbreviation here and italicize the long part:
The first mention with a different inflection ``des \glsdisp{Körper}{Körpers}''.
And here the second use ``der \gls{Körper}''.

The first mention of ``der \gls{Vektor}''.
% Bad; Should choose abbreviation here:
And here with a different inflection ``des \glsdisp{Vektor}{Vektors}''.

\printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abkürzungen]
\end{document}
```

### File `glossary.bib`:

```
@abbreviation{Vektorraum,
short={VR},
long={Vektorraum},
description={Menge von Vektoren mit Vektoraddition und Skalarmultiplikation über einen Körper.},
}
@abbreviation{Vektor,
short={VEC},
long={Vektor},
description={Ein Vektor ist ein Element eines Vektorraums.},
}
@abbreviation{Körper,
short={K},
long={Körper},
description={Zwei kompatible zweistellige Verknüfungen über eine gemeinsame Menge.},
}
```

## Question

Given the requirements, can a `gls` like command be easily created to handle all the above cases, while also respecting the abbreviation style selected and also handle regular glossary terms analogously?

## Existing Solutions

A similar question was posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178725/how-to-use-glossaries-for-different-grammatical-acronym-forms), but the solution sought, was to specify the inflection on usage, whereas I want to call `gls` with a replacement text for the `long` part of the abbreviation on usage to be more practical.

Thanks in advance, even if there is no solution.

## EDIT: Working Example

With the code examples given by Nicola Talbot, the following achieves all requirements (at least, that I can see):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=blue!30!white}

\usepackage[record,abbreviations,nomain]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[abbreviation]{long-postshort-user-desc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{nohyperfirst}{true}
\renewcommand{\glsfirstlonguserfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={glossary},selection=all]
\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{abbreviation}{1}
% Show only terms that are used more than once:
\renewcommand{\printunsrtglossaryhandler}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\GlsXtrTotalRecordCount{#1}>1}%
  {\glsxtrunsrtdo{#1}}%
  {}%
}

\newcommand{\disp}[3][]{%
  \ifglsentryexists{#2}%
  {\glsifregular{#2}%
    {\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
    {\ifglshasshort{#2}%
      {\glsxtrifcounttrigger{#2}%
        {\glsifattribute{#2}{nohyperfirst}{true}%
          {\glslink[hyper=false,#1]{#2}{#3}}%
          {\glslink[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
          \glsunset{#2} }%
        {\ifglsused{#2}%
          {\gls[#1]{#2}}%
          {\glsdisp[textformat=glsfirstlongfont,#1]{#2}{#3}} } }%
      {\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{#3}} } }%
  {\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{3}}%
}

\begin{document}
% The following assertions show the required behavour:
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \disp{Vektorraum}{Vektorraums} & Vektorraums \\ % <- Without link
  \disp{Vektor}{Vektors} & \emph{Vektors} (VEC) \\ % <- Without link
  \disp{Vektor}{Vektors} & VEC \\ % <- With link
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abkürzungen]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

Some things that came up during testing:

- Changing the style from `long-postshort-user-desc` to `long-postshort-user` has the side-effect of removing the long form from the printed glossary listing for some reason.
- Using `\gls` like commands within `$\text{...\gls{Vektor}...}$` behaves weirdly, since each use is counted as 4 occurences with regards to the use counter (`\glsentryprevcount` is 4 times as high).

Otherwise this seems like a splendid solution.

Comment: The `long-postshort-user-desc` style puts the long and short form in the `name` field, leaving the user to supply the `description` field. The `long-postshort-user` style puts the short form in the `name` field and the `long` form in the `description` field. If you set the description it will override this, so the long form won't appear in the glossary. That's the basic difference between those two styles. For your second point, is `$\text{...\gls{Vektor}...}$` inside an environment that parses its contents (such as `tabularx`)? That might require a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two commands that allow you to display custom text encapsulated by the abbreviation formatting commands for a particular category:

- `\glsuseabbrvfont{`*text*`}{`*category*`}`
- `\glsuselongfont{`*text*`}{`*category*`}`

However, these use the *subsequent* (non-first-use) formatting commands. In your example, you've only set the first use long formatting command to `\emph`.

Simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[abbreviation]{long-short-desc}
\renewcommand{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\newabbreviation[description={Ein Vektor ist ein Element eines Vektorraums.}]{Vektor}{VEC}{Vektor}

\begin{document}
First: \gls{Vektor}.

Explicit long: \glsxtrlong{Vektor}.

\glsuselongfont{Vektors}{abbreviation}.
\end{document}
```

In this case only the first use of `\gls` shows the long form in an emphasized font:

[image: First: Vektor (VEC). Explicit long: Vektor. Vektors.]

If non-first-use also needs to be emphasized, then you'd need to redefine `\glslongdefaultfont` instead of `\glsfirstlongdefaultfont`:

```
\renewcommand{\glslongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

This is quite convoluted and using `\glsuselongfont` simply encapsulates the given text, so it's not querying the first use flag or indexing.

With the `glossaries-extra` package, `\gls`, `\glspl`, `\Gls`, `\Glspl`, `\glsdisp` and `\glslink` all use the command `\glsentryfmt` to format the link text. The base `glossaries` package also does this, but the `glossaries-extra` package modifies `\glsentryfmt` to take the abbreviation handling into account:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}{\glssetabbrvfmt{\glscategory{\glslabel}}}{}%
  \glsifregular{\glslabel}%
  {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
  {%
    \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}%
    {\glsxtrabbreviationfont{\glsxtrgenabbrvfmt}}%
    {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
  }%
}
```

This first checks if the entry (whose label can be accessed with `\glslabel`) has the `short` field set. If it does then it switches to the formatting commands associated with that entry's category (`\glssetabbrvfmt{\glscategory{\glslabel}}`).

Then it tests if the entry has the `regular` attribute set for it's category. There are some abbreviation styles that set this attribute because they're designed to behave like regular entries (such as `short-nolong` and `long-noshort`). So even if the `short` field is set, if the `regular` attribute is set then the "regular" general formatting command is used (`\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}`).

If the entry doesn't have the `regular` attribute set and has the `short` field set, then the abbreviation formatting is used instead (`\glsxtrabbreviationfont{\glsxtrgenabbrvfmt}`).

The actual formatting is a bit complicated as it needs to know if this is the first use, whether or not any case-changing (`\Gls`, `\GLS`, `\Glspl`, `\GLSpl`) or plural (`\glspl`, `\Glspl`, `\GLSpl`) is required, or if custom text was provided instead (`\glsdisp` or `\glslink`).

In the case of `\glsdisp` and `\glslink`, just the custom text is displayed. In the other cases it uses one of the commands set up by the abbreviation style:

- `\glsxtrsubsequentplfmt`: subsequent use, plural, no case change.
- `\Glsxtrsubsequentplfmt`: subsequent use, plural, first letter converted to upper case.
- `\glsxtrsubsequentfmt`: subsequent use, singular, no case change.
- `\Glsxtrsubsequentfmt`: subsequent use, singular, first letter converted to upper case.
- `\glsxtrfullplformat`: first use, plural, no case change.
- `\Glsxtrfullplformat`: first use, plural, first letter converted to upper case.
- `\glsxtrfullformat`: first use, singular, no case change.
- `\Glsxtrfullformat`: first use, singular, first letter converted to upper case.

These commands all take two arguments: the label (`\glslabel`) and the inserted material (`\glsinsert`) provided in the final optional argument of `\gls` etc (`\gls[`*options*`]{`*label*`}[`*insert`*]`).

The `long-short-desc` abbreviation style redefines the first use commands as follows (these are actually defined in the inherited `long-short` style):

```
  \renewcommand*{\glsxtrfullformat}[2]{%
    \glsfirstlongfont{\glsaccesslong{##1}\ifglsxtrinsertinside##2\fi}%
    \ifglsxtrinsertinside\else##2\fi
    \glsxtrfullsep{##1}%
    \glsxtrparen{\glsfirstabbrvfont{\glsaccessshort{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsxtrfullplformat}[2]{%
    \glsfirstlongfont{\glsaccesslongpl{##1}\ifglsxtrinsertinside##2\fi}%
    \ifglsxtrinsertinside\else##2\fi\glsxtrfullsep{##1}%
    \glsxtrparen{\glsfirstabbrvfont{\glsaccessshortpl{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Glsxtrfullformat}[2]{%
    \glsfirstlongfont{\Glsaccesslong{##1}\ifglsxtrinsertinside##2\fi}%
    \ifglsxtrinsertinside\else##2\fi\glsxtrfullsep{##1}%
    \glsxtrparen{\glsfirstabbrvfont{\glsaccessshort{##1}}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Glsxtrfullplformat}[2]{%
    \glsfirstlongfont{\Glsaccesslongpl{##1}\ifglsxtrinsertinside##2\fi}%
    \ifglsxtrinsertinside\else##2\fi\glsxtrfullsep{##1}%
    \glsxtrparen{\glsfirstabbrvfont{\glsaccessshortpl{##1}}}%
  }%
```

(The double hash `##` is because these redefinitions are performed inside the style definition command.) If the abbreviation style doesn't explicitly set the subsequent use formatting commands, the defaults are used:

```
\let\glsxtrsubsequentfmt\glsxtrdefaultsubsequentfmt
\let\glsxtrsubsequentplfmt\glsxtrdefaultsubsequentplfmt
\let\Glsxtrsubsequentfmt\Glsxtrdefaultsubsequentfmt
\let\Glsxtrsubsequentplfmt\Glsxtrdefaultsubsequentplfmt
```

So the reference to the `long`, `short`, `longplural` and `shortplural` fields are all hard-coded inside the abbreviation styles. This is necessary to allow the case-changing to work correctly. (The original acronym handling in the base `glossaries` package used a command that took the long form and short form as arguments, but this caused problems for certain styles. It was later replaced with another command that took the label instead.)

One possibility is to redefine `\glsentryfmt` to check for `\glscustomtext` if the entry is an abbreviation. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[abbreviation]{long-short-desc}
\renewcommand{\glslongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}{\glssetabbrvfmt{\glscategory{\glslabel}}}{}%
  \glsifregular{\glslabel}%
  {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
  {%
    \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}%
    {%
      \ifdefempty\glscustomtext
      {%
         \glsxtrabbreviationfont{\glsxtrgenabbrvfmt}%
      }%
      {%
        \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
        {%
          \glsabbrvfont{\glscustomtext}% replace short with custom text
        }%
        {%
          \glsfirstlongfont{\glscustomtext}% replace long with custom text
          \glsxtrfullsep{\glslabel}% separator
          \glsxtrparen{\glsfirstabbrvfont{\glsaccessshort{\glslabel}}}% (short)
        }%
      }%
    }%
    {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
  }%
}

\newabbreviation[description={Ein Vektor ist ein Element eines Vektorraums.}]{Vektor}{VEC}{Vektor}

\begin{document}
First: \gls{Vektor}. Next: \gls{Vektor}.

Reset\glsresetall.

First: \glsdisp{Vektor}{Vektors}. Next: \glsdisp{Vektor}{Vektors}.

\end{document}
```

The first instance of `\glsdisp` swaps the long form for the supplied text. The next instance swaps the short form for the supplied text.

[image: First: Vektor (VEC). Next: VEC. Reset. First: Vektors (VEC). Next: Vektors.]

You can vary this according to your requirements. For example, on subsequent use you might want to ignore the custom text and just use the short form as normal:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}{\glssetabbrvfmt{\glscategory{\glslabel}}}{}%
  \glsifregular{\glslabel}%
  {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
  {%
    \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}%
    {%
      \ifdefempty\glscustomtext
      {%
         \glsxtrabbreviationfont{\glsxtrgenabbrvfmt}%
      }%
      {%
        \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
        {%
          \glsabbrvfont{\glsaccessshort{\glslabel}}% short
        }%
        {%
          \glsfirstlongfont{\glscustomtext}% replace long with custom text
          \glsxtrfullsep{\glslabel}% separator
          \glsxtrparen{\glsfirstabbrvfont{\glsaccessshort{\glslabel}}}% (short)
        }%
      }%
    }%
    {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
  }%
}
```

An alternative method is to use `long-postshort-user-desc` instead of `long-short-desc` (or `long-postshort-user` instead of `long-short` if you decide not to have a description). The "post" styles put the first part of the full form in the link text and the second part in the post-link hook. This means that `\glsdisp` and `\glslink` will only replace the first part with the supplied text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[abbreviation]{long-postshort-user-desc}
\renewcommand{\glsfirstlonguserfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\newabbreviation[description={Ein Vektor ist ein Element eines Vektorraums.}]{Vektor}{VEC}{Vektor}

% syntax: \disp[options]{label}{text}
\newcommand{\disp}[3][]{%
 \GlsXtrIfUnusedOrUndefined
  {#2}%
  {\glsdisp[textformat=glsfirstlongfont,#1]{#2}{#3}}%
  {\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}
First: \gls{Vektor}. Next: \gls{Vektor}.

Reset\glsresetall.

First: \disp{Vektor}{Vektors}. Next: \disp{Vektor}{Vektors}.

\end{document}
```

(The "user" styles use `\glsfirstlonguserfont` to format the long form on first use.)

You may want to consider defining a shortcut command. For example:

```
\newcommand{\disp}[3][]{%
 \GlsXtrIfUnusedOrUndefined
  {#2}%
  {\glsdisp[textformat=glsfirstlongfont,#1]{#2}{#3}}%
  {\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
}
```

(Since you're using `bib2gls`, it's better to use `\GlsXtrIfUnusedOrUndefined` instead of `\ifglsused`.) The style-sensitive `\glsfirstlongfont` is set by `\glssetabbrvfmt` at the start of `\glsentryfmt`, so it can be used in this context.

The result is:

[image: First: Vektor (VEC). Next: VEC. Reset. First: Vektors (VEC). Next: Vektors.]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I slightly modified your `long-postshort-desc` method to respect the entry counting and reported the solution in my question. As it is, this works fine :)