# How to output value of entry key with glossaries-extra and bib2gls?

Tags: glossaries-extra, bib2gls

For reasons similar to [this question's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178725/183394) (noun declension), I wish to refer to an entry and output an arbitrary text (in this case, a particular declension of the entry noun). It looks like entering the text as key-value pairs in the entry is a good solution.

However, the answer to the linked question only supplies an answer in vanilla `glossaries`. I use `glossaries-extra` with `bib2gls` and I'm not sure how to convert between them.

For the entry

```
@entry{duck,
    name = {anka},
    description = {A bird},
    definitiveplural = {ankorna}
}
```

I would like to output

> ankorna

with a hyperlink to the glossary as with other terms.

My best guess has been `\glsxtrusefield{duck}{definitiveplural}` from page 194 in [the manual](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.pdf), with no output as result. The manual does mention that I should use the internal field tag, but I'm not sure how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed,

`\glsxtrusefield{duck}{definitiveplural}`

is correct. However, this custom key needs to be defined first like this

```
\glsaddstoragekey{definitiveplural}{}{\DefinitivePlural} % Placed before \GlsXtrLoadResources
```

as noted in the [`bib2gls` intro](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/support/bib2gls/bib2gls-begin.pdf), p. 11. This also lets you use

```
\DefinitivePlural{duck}
```

for the same effect.

---

Internal field tags for the default keys are listed in the [`glossaries` manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf), p. 108, as noted in the `glossaries-extra` manual.