# Indexing, making glossaries in languages with inflections

Tags: glossaries, indexing, german

I would like to add a glossary at the end of my book which would also feature a list of the page number (indices), where the given book number can be found.

This can be done by the standard `glossaries` package, however, it only seems to support English, as it only can display the word's singular and plural form in the text. `\gls{ }` and `\glspl{ }` commands. What should I do if I need to support a language which has many inflexions (Accusative, Dative, Genitive etc.) and in addition to this often has words appearing as part of a longer word, or maybe an abbreviation?

In summary, I would like to have a glossary command which would typeset the word in the desired form and link it to the respective glossary entry.

Comment: [How to use glossaries for different grammatical acronym forms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178725/134144)  might be helpful.

Comment: Not entirely. The commands seem pretty impractical and unreadable in source code. Plus, how would you cope with a language like Hungarian, which has over 20 cases for both plural and singular nouns and a petorah of tenses and modes for verbs. Furthermore, as I tried to explain: I would like to link the words "illiterate", "semiliterate" and "literate" to the same glossary entry. Should I creaate a custom  command for each possibility? This is non feasible even in english.