# Change appearance of acronym according to grammatical form

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am using the `glossaries` package with the option `acronym` as a list of abbreviations. To refer to the acronyms I use the commands `\acrfull{}`, `\acrlong{}` and `\acrshort{}`. Since I am writing in German I have to use some different grammatical forms of my acronyms and it is not always possible to change the sentence to fit with the form defined in the glossary. So is there a way to change the appearance of a glossaryentry in the document but still linking to a acronym or some other way of workaround? I am aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178725/how-to-use-glossaries-for-different-grammatical-acronym-forms) asking a similar thing, but is seems quite complicated to me to define all these different grammatical forms. It would be way easier if there was something like `\acrfull[text in document]{linked acronym}`.

**Here a MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nonumberlist,nopostdot,nogroupskip,section=subsection]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setglossarystyle{super}
\makenoidxglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newacronym{MGA}{MGA}{Mittlerer Geometrischer Abstand}

\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossary[title=Acronyme, type=\acronymtype]

Der \acrfull{MGA} ist eine geometrische Größe.
\end{document}
```

**What I get:**

[image]

**What I want:** (correct grammatical appearance)

The grammatical correct sentence in this case would be: 'Der Mittlere Geometrische Abstand ist eine geometrische Größe.'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast search in the docu for "link" lead to this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nonumberlist,nopostdot,nogroupskip,section=subsection]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setglossarystyle{super}
\makenoidxglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newacronym{MGA}{MGA}{Mittlerer Geometrischer Abstand}

\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossary[title=Acronyme, type=\acronymtype]

Der \glslink{MGA}{blub} ist eine geometrische Größe.


\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]